# Detect if my ANN model is overfitted

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, tensorflow

I've been trying the kaggle dataset of Credit card fraud detection [Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) . I've used ANN using keras and tensorflow. You can find the code in the screenshot. The only problem is im getting accuracy to be around 99.9 % , so i think it's surely a case of some false hopes or over fitting. Can you please tell whats wrong with it? And even my test set gave a result of 99.93% accuracy.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Data Science StackExchange! Please avoid posting code as image: it is not easily read, cannot be copy-pasted, and generates unnecessary hosting.

Comment: Please provide train and test loss graphs, there we can check for problems, and accuracy 99.9 %, is it train accuracy or validation accuracy?

Comment: hey , sorry i didnt knwo about that. @Elbek the training set as well as test set accuracy is 99.9 % .And is it possible to show graphs even for independent 30 independent variables?

Comment: @GauravRoy just show graph of loss

Comment: any link how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

> This dataset presents transactions that occurred in two days, where we have 492 frauds out of 284,807 transactions. The dataset is highly unbalanced, the positive class (frauds) account for 0.172% of all transactions.

I guess your model learnt nothing at all ;)

You should consider some form of resampling and using metrics that can handle imbalance.
[This](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) might be a good starting point. You can find bunch of similar threads here as well.

Comment: okay , so why didnt my model learn anything? didnt get that part? i should have a balanced dataset for that? and how to tackle it?

Comment: Your model overfits to over-represented class. You can just output `not-fraud` all the time and you'll get 83% accuracy. Accuracy is counted globally and doesn't account for imbalance. Check this [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/arjunjoshua/predicting-fraud-in-financial-payment-services) and [this](https://www.kaggle.com/mandan/kernel-fraud-detection) one. Before you jump into DNN you should first explore more classical models like `random forest` or `xgboost`, they're much faster to fit. This data set is rather tough and you won't get away with just simple rescaler.

Comment: oh okay, great. thanks. got to know something new. will ask if any doubgs

Comment: Ups, got my math wrong. Constant `not-fraud` model would give you 99.3% accuracy.

Comment: basic question , on how to learn more of machine learning and CNN? like any tips?

Comment: Do projects. People learn by experience. Watching tutorials will get you nowhere. When it comes to DNN it's nice to have someone holding your hand and start from basics. [This](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/deep-learning-computer-vision-python-book/) is great book. Cannot recommend it more.

Comment: great, thanks a lot.